# How to copy text (Questions & Answers) from a Windows Notepad to a Microsoft Word template file?

Tags: copy-paste, notepad, microsoft

Following are the details:

1. The Windows Notepad text consists of Questions and corresponding Answers, generated ASR software.  All Questions and Answers start in a new line.
2. Microsoft Word file is a template file consists of formatting like line numbers on the left, fixed spacing between lines, and so on.
3. First line of the Word document starts with alphabet "Q" then four spaces.
4. Second line of the Word document starts with alphabet "A" then four spaces.

I need you to suggest a way where, with minium time, I should be able to copy each Question from the Notepad file and then paste to the Word file, in front of alphabet Q after four spaces.  Similarly, copy the corresponding answer from the Notepad file and paste it to the Word file, in front of alphabet A after four spaces.

Comment: It would be simpler to use some evolved text editor, such as Notepad++, to add the "A" and "Q" text to the original text, copy that to Word, and do the required formatting changes using Word's Find and Replace dialog. If you would like more information, please add to your question the notepad text for a couple of Q&As as example.